# Amazon RDS: Should I Stop or Terminate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have some RDS instance that I don't use a lot, but also don't want to delete them as I might need them in future. 
Now, if I do stop the instances, AWS automatically starts them back after 7 days.

So I am using aws cli and setting up a cron job to automatically stop them after 7 days.

```
aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier my-db-instance1
```

The same way for all other instances.

```
0 0 * * 7 /etc/cron.daily/script.sh
```

I don't believe its the best practice. Can anybody help me understand how could I create a config file which has my instance ID's so that my script reads from it and populates the instance ID's?

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you very rarely use the database and you don't want it starting again after 7 days, then you should [create a **snapshot**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html) of the instance and then **terminate** it.

The instance will not auto-start. You will need to [restore the snapshot to a new database instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html) when you wish to use it, which can be done from the command-line.

Comment: It's not very rarely that I use it, but I would not like to terminate it as well. 
Any other work-around to my problem?

Comment: You only have the choice of terminating it, then restoring from backup. Or, stop it (which I suspect does a similar thing), but it forces a restart after 7 days. Snapshot + terminate is the wisest choice and can be automated.

Comment: Restoring a database of up-to 1 TB in size can take a lot of time.
Hence, I was looking for automating it with script.